# Python Sqlite3 raises error when extracting all the matches by using LIKE

Tags: python, sqlite

I have problems with extracting data from the db, when the below function is called with the default parameter for audio_name = '', the error is rised:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

This is the function:

```
   def extract_audio(self, audio_name = ''):
        with self.connection:
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Audio WHERE audio LIKE '%'||?||'%'"
            self.my_cursor.execute(sql, audio_name)
            audio = self.my_cursor.fetchall()
        print(audio)
        return audio
```

I made this function from tutorials, for them it was working perfectly, so the problem might be the empty string passed. I need a solution!

Answer (score 1):

So I basically changed the way I was executing the query to:

```
self.my_cursor.execute(sql, (audio_name,))
```

and now it's working!